# ConfirmationActivity wearable how to?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have a problem with the implementation **ConfirmationActivity**. When I downloaded the full *API reference documentation*, and looked the part about ConfirmationActivity, I saw only one method `onCreate` and do not understand how to implement animation like in demos. When I search in `sdk/templates/` I don't find any. Help me please.

There is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "text";

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        setTitle(getTextExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, "Title"));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(getTextExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, "text"));
        findViewById(R.id.ok).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private String getTextExtra(String extra, String def) {
        final String text = getIntent().getStringExtra(extra);
        if (text == null) {
            return def;
        } else {
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this one

```
public static void showSuccessActivity(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConfirmationActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE, ConfirmationActivity.SUCCESS_ANIMATION);

    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Саня, от души, братан! :D